# What is the identity map for the change of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

$_B[f]_B=_B[id]_A \circ {_A}[f]_A\circ{_A[id]_B}$

So form example given the orthogonal basis $B=(1,1,1);(1,1,-2);(1,-1,0)$ and $A=(e_1,e_2,e_3)$

What is meant by ${_A[id]_B}$? in $R^3$

I know how to compute $_B[f]_B$, given $f$, but I'm not understanding the identity elements, and $_A[f]_A$

Can someone compute ${_A[id]_B}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary element $ v \in  \mathbb{R}^3$. There are two ways to represent this vector,

$$v = a(1,0,0) + b(0,1,0) + c(0,0,1) $$

$$v = \alpha (1,1,1) + \beta (1,1,-1) + \gamma (1,-1,0) $$

**How to find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ given $a,b,c$ ?**

The answer is ${_A[id]_B}$, indeed this matrix is designed so that

$$_A[id]_B \left(\begin{matrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ \end{matrix} \right) = \left(\begin{matrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \\ \end{matrix} \right)$$

**How to compute ${_A[id]_B}$ ?**

The above equality shows that the matrix ${_A[id]_B}$ has entries $m_{i,j} $ defined  by

$$(1,0,0) =  m_{1,1} (1,1,1) + m_{2,1} (1,1,-2) + m_{3,1} (1,-1,0) $$
$$(0,1,0) =  m_{1,2} (1,1,1) + m_{2,2} (1,1,-2) + m_{3,2} (1,-1,0) $$
$$(0,0,1) =  m_{1,3} (1,1,1) + m_{2,3} (1,1,-2) + m_{3,3} (1,-1,0) $$

Comment: I see, so that would mean that $_B[id]_A$ is simply my basis, $B=b_1,b_2,b_3$ since, $(1,1,1)=e_1+e_2+e_3$ etc.

Comment: Yes, $_B[id]_A$  will have as columns $b_1,b_2,b_3$

Comment: Is there an easy way to remember which way round it is? Also, it means that $[id]$ doesn't actually correspond to the identity matrix, which I though it did originaly

Comment: Not that I know of, I still have to think about it each time